# Firebase.auth() deprecated?

Tags: javascript, web, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebasesimplelogin

I was following an official firebase tutorial on creating a login page. I receive a warning that FirebaseRef.auth() is being deprecated and to use FirebaseRef.authWithCustomToken() instead. Any code after calling the firebase. auth() method doesn't run. Based on Google results this has been an issue since 2014, but the tutorial came out July 26 2016.    Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the link to the tutorial you're following and the code that is giving you problems. Without that it'll be hard to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen https://youtu.be/-OKrloDzGpU   calling the .auth()  method returns a warning and does not execute subsequent code.

Comment: I just went through that video on speedrun and saw no mention of `authWithCustomToken`. To get the auth service, call `firebase.auth()` If you're having problems: please edit your question to include the minimal code that reproduces the problem. And definitely follow Nishant's advice to start from the latest docs.

Comment: Don't know why you are being down voted. I am getting misinformation as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a lot of changes in the new Firebase version. For example, earlier we were required to setup the context by creating an Application and calling it in the Manifest. Now this is not required. Like wise there are many changes/improvisations in the new version.

Firebase documentation provides enough code to get you started:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth

Or you can go through this series of video, excellent they are:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGCjwl1RrtcTXrWuRTa59RyRmQ4OedWrt

Comment: Thanks. Simples, cleared some conflicting firebase code